# Adding suffix to a list with foreach

Tags: phing

I am including a .properties file, which has a list of properties:

```
configuration.files = file1, file2

configuration.files.file1.source      = config/filename1
configuration.files.file2.source      = config/filename2
```

Now I need the paths for each file changed to something like this:

```
vendor/project/config/filename1
vendor/project/config/filename2
```

To achieve that, I tried to foreach this list and prepend that suffix and overriding the existing property:

```
<foreach list="${configuration.files}" target="_prepend-vendor-path" param="file" >
    <property name="configuration.files.${file}.source" value="/vendor/project/${configuration.files.${file}.source}" override="true"/>
</foreach>

<target name="_prepend-vendor-path" >
    <echo msg="${configuration.files.${file}.source}" />
</target>
```

This doesn't work and I can't figure out why. Is it even possible to use target names like ${suffix}.name ? If not, how could I achive my goal here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did some workaround for this, writing out the properties and their values to a file and readin them after the loop has finished with `override = true`:

```
<target name="_prepend-vendor-path" >
    <exec dir="${project.basedir}" command="echo configuration.files.${file}.source = /vendor/project/${configuration.files.${file}.source} >> ${project.temp.config}" passthru="true" checkreturn="true" />
</target>
```

and after the foreach simply:

```
<property file="${project.temp.config}" override="true"/>
```

For some reason the properties won't be overridden in the foreach and I just can't figgure out why, but this little trick made it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can suffix your property values from your file with the [property](https://www.phing.info/phing/guide/en/output/hlhtml/#PropertyTask) task using a [filterchain](https://www.phing.info/phing/guide/en/output/hlhtml/#app.corefilters) and a [regular expression replacement](https://www.phing.info/phing/guide/en/output/hlhtml/#ReplaceRegexp):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="Phing Build Tests" default="append-custom-path" basedir=".">
    <target name="append-custom-path">
        <property file="prop.properties">
            <filterchain>
                <replaceregexp>
                    <regexp pattern="^(.*)" replace="vendor/project/$1"/>
                </replaceregexp>
            </filterchain>
        </property>
        <echo>${configuration.files.file1.source}</echo>
        <echo>${configuration.files.file2.source}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```